# No provider for ComponentLoaderFactory

Tags: angular

I updated my angular2 project and before it was working fine. However now I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./RibbonComponent class 
RibbonComponent - inline template:4:5 caused by: No provider for 
ComponentLoaderFactory!
Error: Error in ./RibbonComponent class RibbonComponent - inline 
template:4:5 caused by: No provider for ComponentLoaderFactory!
```

ComponentLoaderFactory

```
export declare class ComponentLoaderFactory {
    private _componentFactoryResolver;
    private _ngZone;
    private _injector;
    private _posService;
    constructor(componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, ngZone: NgZone, injector: Injector, posService: PositioningService);
    /**
     *
     * @param _elementRef
     * @param _viewContainerRef
     * @param _renderer
     * @returns {ComponentLoader}
     */
    createLoader<T>(_elementRef: ElementRef, _viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef, _renderer: Renderer): ComponentLoader<T>;
}
```

I am not sure what else to post. All my made my package.json up to date via `ncu` than `ncu -u`. I am being to think I found a bug. I did find a post on GitHub but it did not help. [GitHub](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/issues/1348)

If I need to post anything else let me know.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Not sure what libraries you are using, but I had this error when using `ng2-bootstrap`.

I got the solution from this page: [angular-2-with-ng2-bootstrap-and-karma-testing-final-adventure](https://web.archive.org/web/20170420095211/http://www.indexoutofbounds.net/2016/12/25/angular-2-with-ng2-bootstrap-and-karma-testing-final-adventure/).

Essentially the problem was with an import that required the `.forRoot()` method to be called. Maybe look for something similar in the RibbonComponent or other imported library.

Comment: Yes, I suffered from the same problem. In your test spec, you need to include `ModalModule.forRoot()` in your imports section.

Comment: This solved the issue for me as well forgot to add the "forRoot" method.

Answer (score 21):

for example is you are using modal of ngx-bootstrap then you should import the module in spec.ts like :-

```
ModalModule.forRoot()
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This answer is the same as the one that has already been accepted.

Answer (score 5):

import modal module in your spec.ts file like this:

```
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
....
imports: [ModalModule.forRoot()],
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case my test was missing this import:

```
TooltipModule.forRoot()
```

it is strange that for other modules, such as `ModalModule`, I get a proper error that points me to the missing provider, but not for this one.