# Angular 6 custom lib No provider for ComponentFactoryResolver

Tags: angular, dynamic, components, angular-cli, angular6

I rewriting library from NG4 -> NG6 (using angular-cli 6). This lib change dynamicli angular components so I using `ComponentFactoryResolver` and here I got stuck. When I add `ComponentFactoryResolver` to constructor:

```
constructor(
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
) {}
```

and build lib (with success) in target app (I add my lib in package.json from local file) I have this error:

```
StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MyLibComponent-> ComponentFactoryResolver]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MyLibComponent-> ComponentFactoryResolver]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ComponentFactoryResolver!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:979)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1232)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1182)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1077)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1232)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1182)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1077)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:9238)
    at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:9919)
```

Without `ComponentFactoryResolver` other things work correct

Full component:

```
import { Component, ComponentFactoryResolver, AfterContentInit, ViewChild, Inject, Input, InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

import { AbHostDirective } from './../directives/ab-host.directive';

export const AB_COMPONENTS = new InjectionToken('AB_COMPONENTS');

@Component({
  selector: 'lib-ab',
  template: `<ng-template lib-ab-host></ng-template>`,
  styles: []
})

export class MyLibComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @ViewChild(AbHostDirective) abHost: AbHostDirective;
  @Input() globalConfiguration: any;
  @Input() domain = '';

  constructor(
    @Inject(AB_COMPONENTS) private $configuredComponents: any,
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
  ) {}

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    const currentConfiguration = this.$configuredComponents[this.domain];

    if (!currentConfiguration) {
        console.error('No component for: ', + this.domain);
        return;
    }

    const randomIndex      = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentConfiguration.length);
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(currentConfiguration[randomIndex]);
    const viewContainerRef = this.abHost.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.clear();
    const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    const instance     = <any>componentRef.instance;
    instance.globalConfiguration     = this.globalConfiguration;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you add `ComponentFactoryResolver` to the import from `@angular/core`? We may need to see more of your code that what you have included.

Comment: Yes I import (I edit my orginal post)

Comment: Are you using *ng2-bootstrap* by chance? If so, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41748662/no-provider-for-componentloaderfactory). Are you using any other libraries that may require calling `.forRoot()` explicitly? Have any components that should be been added to the `entryComponents` array in the library module? [Ref](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

Comment: With `.forRoot()` I use `UIRouterModule.forRoot` and `TranslateModule.forRoot` I don't use ng2-bootstrap

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. This ticked solved my problem:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20598

Try adding this to your angular.json file:

```
"build": {
    "options": {
        "preserveSymlinks": true,
    }
}
```