# Angular 6 lib provider error

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular6, angular-library

I know that this question is similar to [Angular 6 custom lib No provider for ComponentFactoryResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50192379/angular-6-custom-lib-no-provider-for-componentfactoryresolver).

> Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AppComponent -> NgRestModelService]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AppComponent -> NgRestModelService]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for NgRestModelService!

[To see full code visit the repo on GitHub](https://github.com/mfodor/ng-rest-model/tree/feature/angular6).

I've followed the [documentations of Angular](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services) (and [Angular's example code](https://stackblitz.com/angular/rdyygmoglor?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcore%2Fcore.module.ts)) but this error is shown.

The case in brief: there is a service that should be configured with base URL of the API but the configuration is not provided to the service's constructor even though it is present in the `forRoot()` method of the NgModule.

App module:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        NgRestModelModule.forRoot({
            baseUrl: 'http://localhost:5656/api'
        }),
    ],
    providers: [Denomination],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Lib module:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [],
    declarations: [],
    exports: [],
    providers: [NgRestModelService]
})
export class NgRestModelModule {
    static forRoot(config: INgRestModelConfig): ModuleWithProviders {
        console.log('forRoot got ', config);
        return {
            ngModule: NgRestModelModule,
            providers: [
                {provide: NgRestModelConfig, useValue: config}
            ]
        };
    }

    constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: NgRestModelModule) {
        if (parentModule) {
            throw new Error(
                'NgRestModelModule is already loaded. Import it in the AppModule only');
        }
    }
}
```

Lib service:

```
export class NgRestModelConfig implements INgRestModelConfig {
    http: HttpClient;
    baseUrl: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class NgRestModelService {

    // ...

    constructor(
        private _http: HttpClient,
        @Optional() config: NgRestModelConfig,
    ) {
        console.log('consturcting NgRestModelService, config: ', config);
        if (config) {
            this.configure(config);
        }
    }

    // ...

}
```