# ComponentFactoryResolver inside component library

Tags: angular, angular-dynamic-components

I have created the "library" type of project using Angular CLI.

Inside, I have component MyComponent and inside it the following constructor:

```
constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {      }
```

MyComponent is registered inside of its module (declarations and exports). This module also imports "CommonModule".

However, once I try to use this library (built version) in the other app I am getting the following:

```
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MyComponent -> ComponentFactoryResolver]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MyComponent -> ComponentFactoryResolver]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ComponentFactoryResolver!
    at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:97227:27)
    at resolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:112144:24)
    at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:112070:16)
    at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:111920:20)
    at resolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:112144:24)
    at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:112070:16)
    at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:111920:20)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:123107:29)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:124173:16)
    at resolveDep (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:124704:45)
```

I tried with this but with no help: [Angular 6 custom lib No provider for ComponentFactoryResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50192379/angular-6-custom-lib-no-provider-for-componentfactoryresolver)

Versions

Angular CLI: 8.3.10

Node: 10.14.2

OS: darwin x64

Angular: 8.2.11